# Geodesics with inverse accelerations in a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth embedded submanifold. Consider $S$ as a Riemannian manifold, with the induced metric which comes from the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Is it possible that there exist two geodesics $\gamma,\beta$ in $S$, starting at some $p \in S$, such that $\ddot \gamma(0)=-\ddot \beta(0) \neq 0$?

Here $\ddot \gamma(0),\ddot \beta(0)$ are the extrinsic accelerations, i.e. the accelerations of $\gamma,\beta$ when we view them as paths in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What about $S=\{z=x^2-y^2\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and the lines $\{y=0\},\{x=0\}\subset S$?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong , but I don't think that $\alpha(t)=(0,t,-t^2)$ is a geodesic. The requirement is $\ddot \alpha(t) \perp T_{\alpha(t)}S$. Here $\ddot \alpha(t) =(0,0,-2)$, but $T_{\alpha(t)}S$ is not the $x-y$ plane for $t \neq 0$.

Comment: I believe it has to be a geodesic, maybe you chose the wrong parametrization. Luckily enough, though, there is a simple criterion for geodesics up to reparametrizations.

Comment: Let's put it this way - shoot two geodesics from the origin, in the directions of the x and y-axes. They have to satisfy what you asked about.